# Can I add both a banner ad at bottom and a native ad at top of the screen in the same activity admob android

Tags: android, admob, native, ads, banner

I've published an app on the Google Play Store and it got some decent downloads. So, I decided to increase the ads in order to get good revenue. So, in my home screen activity I had a banner ad at the bottom and now I want to place another native ad on the top of the screen. I don't know if it's okay with the AdMob policies or if I'm going to face any issues

I want to add a small_size native ad on the top I don't know whether I should remove the banner ad or not.

Comment: No, You can use both at same time.